# Text editor for web developement with SSH

Tags: editor

Ive been developing all my life in Linux and now I have to work in a Windows 7 system. I would like to know what editor could I use with SSH, so I could edit the files directly on the server.

I guess Im not going to find anything good looking like coda or textmate, but at least Id like the SSH feature and syntaxis highlighting.

Also I need it to be free, and preferably lightweight.

Suggestions, please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/824327/446747

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution finally presented itself. Sublime Text 2 :)

Answer (score 2):

I generally use [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) for editing remote files … and local files. It is a nice, cross-platform editor.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), their NppFTP-Extension (should be included by default) supports remote file editing.
Or as mention in the link above: WinSCP and NP++ as default editor.

Answer (score 0):

I have given an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15099505/661933). [Bluefish](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/index.html) can be the answer you're looking for as its primarily targeted towards web development.